# Replace characters in old array

Tags: c++

I'm solving a problem and stuck on last part now what i am doing. Taking 5 characters from user and save it on character array and than saying enter 3 characters to check does array has your enter characters in it. 

**For example:** 
User enter 5 characters `dagpl`.
Than second array `subArray` which search characters from main array now user enter 3 characters`dgl`.
Result saying 3 characters found. Are you want to replace these 3 characters with new characters? So enter 3 new replace characters  now user enter `xyz`.
Final array would be replace like this `xaypz`.

My Code doesn't working fine for replacing characters i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    bool check = false;

    char arr[6] = { '\0' };

    char subarr[4] = { '\0' };

    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter Characters : ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        cin >> arr[i];
    }


    cout << "Enter 3 Characters and see how many times does array has your Search Characters : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        cin >> subarr[i];
    }

    //Sub Array
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {


            if (subarr[i] == arr[j]) {
                if (!check) {
                    cout << "Found characters are: ";
                }
                count++;
                cout << subarr[i] << ",";
                check = true;

            }
        }

    }

    if (check) {
        cout << '\b';
        cout << " ";
        cout << endl;

    }
    if (!check) {
        cout << "Sorry Nothing Found" << endl;
    }
    cout << "total Found : " << count << endl;

    //SECTION 3
    if (check) {
        int n = count + 1;
        char* replace = new char[n]();
        cout << "You can only replace " << count << " new characters because of find operation! so enter it will be replace old array with it: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            cin >> replace[i];

        }

        //Replace characters
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (subarr[i] == arr[j]) {

                    arr[j] = replace[j];


                }

            }
        }

        delete[]replace;
        replace = NULL;


        cout << "New Array would be: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            cout << arr[i];


        }


        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see where it goes wrong. Something tels me it might have something to do with you indexing `replace` *out of bounds*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you can only enter 5 characters in first array and any 3 characters for search

Comment: Yes and that means `count` will be at *most* `3`, right? Then in the replacement loop you use the index `j` which will go up to `4`, which could be out of bounds. By the way, shouldn't the index for `arr` go up to *5*? That will *guarantee* that `replace` will be indexed out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not marking the matched characters from `arr`
Replace the matched characters from `arr[j]` with a distinct character so that you can determine where to replace later. you can use `null terminator`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (subarr[i] == arr[j]) {
                if (!check) {
                    cout << "Found characters are: ";
                }
                count++;
                cout << subarr[i] << ",";
                check = true;
                arr[j]='\0'; //replacing the matched character with null terminator
            }
        }
    }
```

Now traverse through your `arr` and replace null terminators with characters from `replace` array

```
   int i=0;

   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      if (arr[j]=='\0') { //replace when it equals to null terminator
         arr[j] = replace[i++];
       }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Code dumps aren't answers, Shubho.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a bit late here, I updated my answer. Thank you

Comment: It's still not an explanation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does it look better now?

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask the user to replace a specific number of chars, counting how many chars appear in subarr.

arr is input, subarr is from:

```
int replacecount[3] = { 0 };

for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        if (input[x] == from[i]) {
            ++replacecount[i];
            break;
        }

int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    if (replacecount[i] > 0)
        ++count;

std::cout << " you can replace " << count << " characters..." << std::endl;
char to[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    if (replacecount[i] > 0) {
        std::cout << "enter replace character for '" << from[i] << "'" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> to[i];
    }

for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        if (input[x] == from[i]) {
            input[x] = to[i];
            break;
        }

 std::cout << "replaced string is: " << input << std::endl;
```